# Do you come? Are you coming?

Tags: present-tense, continuous

What are the differences between these questions:

- Do you come?
- Are you coming?

Which is the more correct usage?

If I first say "It's late. I'm going home now," which is the correct form of this question:

- Are you coming with me?
- Do you come with me.

Answer (score 5):

> Do you come?

is an incomplete question which would lead the listener to wonder "Do you come *what*?"

> Do you come here often?

would be a more complete question.

> Are you coming?

is a complete question asking whether *someone* will join you in your travels.

The same applies in your next two sentences

> Are you coming with me?  *(correct)*
>   Do you come with me. *(incorrect)*

However, if you change "do" to "will"

> *Will* you come?
>   *Will* you come with me?

you will have two correct questions with what you possibly intended in your original meaning.

Comment: Further to Peter's comprehensive answer "Do you come here often?" completes the question in a continuous form, as opposed to the more obviously present "Are you coming?"

"Do you come with me?" is certainly archaic and if it was used today it would seem strange, but at a guess it sounded comfortable for about 1,000 years until early Victorian dates.